# Unable to add "Authorization" header in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, header, authorization

When using http get requests we need to pass the authorization header field. But i am getting a runtime error when I am using 'Authorization' as a key in headers. If I comment that header or change the header key I get an Unauthorized error.[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMXcE.png). [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgu4U.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Make sure, when you ask a question, you include the code (vs the image you provided) in the question so that it is searchable in case anyone else has the same issue.

Comment: Also, try to remove the blocked portion with dummy data if it's sensitive. We cannot fully analyze code issues if things are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The `http` package also includes `HttpHeaders` class.

Try replacing:

```
"Authorization": 'Bearer $jwtToken',
```

with:

```
HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $jwtToken',
```

`HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader` ends up being just a string returning `"authorization"`, but it's worth a shot.

Source: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests

---

UPDATE:

Also, `URI.parse` is not needed in this scenario. I assume the blocked code is a URL string, remove the `URI.parse` portion.